# Открытие RTF в отдельном потоке

Tags: c#, wpf, rtf

Есть код открывающий файл rtf в RichTextBox`е.

```
byte[] result;
                FileStream file = File.Open(TextURI, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
                result = new byte[file.Length];
                await file.ReadAsync(result, 0, (int)file.Length);
                MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
               await memStream.WriteAsync(result, 0, (int)file.Length);
                file.Close();
                var tr = new TextRange(rtf.Document.ContentStart, rtf.Document.ContentEnd);
                tr.Load(memStream, DataFormats.Rtf);
                memStream.Close();
```

Каким образом можно сделать это в отдельном потоке, чтобы приложение не замораживалось пока файл открывается? Все время пишет "Поток был недоступен для чтения." на строчке

```
tr.Load(memStream, DataFormats.Rtf);
```

Comment: "Поток был недоступен для чтения." пишет когда пытаюсь в отдельный поток вывести

Comment: Из того, что вижу, навскидку, перемотать MemoryStream в начало надо...

Да и не совсем понятно, зачем вообще промежуточный поток нужен...

Comment: ну можно и без него конечно, сути не меняет) нужно вынести

    tr.Load(memStream, DataFormats.Rtf);
    
в отдельный поток, чтобы приложение не тормозило пока файл открывается...

Comment: Ну, я помню тему, да. Вот только тормоз не от открытия файла и не от чтения, а от загрузки всей этой кучи "буковок" в RichTextBox.

Comment: и это никак не лечится? я все же надеюсь есть способы "не визуальной" загрузки. То есть, нажал открыть файл, и что то на форме происходит, пока весь текст грузится в RTB, а потом разом проявляется

Comment: Я писал в той теме пример с постепенной загрузкой и "передышками" основному потоку. На мой взгляд вполне себе вариант, разве что при больших объемах текста без переносом будет заметно подтормаживание.

Так или иначе, даже если все красиво загрузить, на отрисовку элемента управления у WPF уйдет время, да и крупный текст еще и скроллируется плохо, так тормозов будет предостаточно.

Comment: я не знаю как применить загрузку с передышками к RTF. Средний текст это 3-4 страницы вордовских 12 шрифтом. Да это мало, но тормоза вызывает почему то.


Возможно ли отдать больший приоритет графике в приложении?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в Вашем RTF всё-таки есть переносы на следующую строку, то вот такой пример должен работать...

```
    using (var fs = new StreamReader(new FileStream("d:\\1.rtf", FileMode.Open)))
        while (!fs.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = await fs.ReadLineAsync();
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(fs.CurrentEncoding.GetBytes(line)))
            {
                new TextRange(doc.ContentEnd, doc.ContentEnd).Load(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);
                await Task.Delay(10);
            }
        }
```

Жуткий костыль и с первой строкой могут возникнуть трудности, но в целом прокатывает.

doc - rtf.Document, в Вашем случае.

Если переносов нет, то могу посоветовать почитать спецификацию формата RTF и найти разделители, которые позволят грузить текст частями.

---

Попробуйте ещё вот такое "счастье" запустить. Насколько лучше?

```
    TextRange range = new TextRange(doc.ContentStart, doc.ContentEnd);
    var TextEditorCopyPaste = typeof(TextRange).Assembly.GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == "TextEditorCopyPaste");
    var ConvertRtfToXaml = TextEditorCopyPaste.GetMethod("ConvertRtfToXaml", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    var WpfPayload = typeof(TextRange).Assembly.GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == "WpfPayload");
    var LoadElement = WpfPayload.GetMethod("LoadElement", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("c:\\0101.rtf");
    MemoryStream stream = await Task.Run<MemoryStream>(async () => ConvertRtfToXaml.Invoke(null, new object[] { await reader.ReadToEndAsync() }) as MemoryStream);
    TextElement element = LoadElement.Invoke(null, new object[] { stream }) as TextElement;
    typeof(TextRange).GetMethod("SetXmlVirtual", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Invoke(range, new object[] { element });
```

Пояснение для кучи непонятных буковок :-)

[Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183(v=vs.80).aspx) - мощная возможность обращаться к любому методу/свойству/полю/событию и т.д.
Это не определение, понятное дело, но для текущего использования этого достаточно.

Если покопаться в исходниках того, как Microsoft загружает RTF в свой RichTextBox, то можно обнаружить следующую последовательность. Сначала поток считывается в MemoryStream, затем он из MemoryStream считывается в виде текста, который затем конвертируют из RTF в XAML представление, а потом создаётся уже объект TextElement, который на самом деле и вставляется в RichTextBox.

В первых 4-х строчках я нахожу нужные мне типы и методы, которые Microsoft по тем или иным причинам не стал делать публичными, однако, дотфускацию кода они тоже не делают и в исходниках вполне можно копаться.

Как это принято у Microsoft, типы с довольно длинными и говорящими названиями. TextEditorCopyPaste - явно отвечает за всякую вставку текста в текстовый редактор. Тип находится в той же сборке, что и TextRange. Из него нам нужен один метод - ConvertRtfToXaml (из названия уже тоже понятно что это и зачем). Метод (как и сам тип) не публичный, но для Reflection это не помеха, так что достаём и тот и другой.
Аналогично поступаем и с типом WpfPayload и нужным нам методом LoadElement. Этот метод отвечает за создание объекта TextElement из XAML (который в потоке тем не менее лежит).

После того как все приготовления завершены (на них в коде уходят считанные миллисекунды, кстати).

Далее начинаем непосредственно загружать.

Загрузку в строку мы можем выполнить и сами, да ещё и асинхронно, что я и делаю в строке

```
await reader.ReadToEndAsync()
```

Этот текст мы должны передать в метод ConvertRtfToXaml. Так как Microsoft внутри метода вызывает неасинхронные и довольно прожорливые методы (порядка 1.5 секунд теряли тут именно), то я вынес обработку нашего текста в отдельный поток.

На выходе получаем опять MemoryStream, но уже с XAML (кажется там даже сразу XAML Package).

Этот MemoryStream мы передаём методу LoadElement, который выполняется примерно 200 миллисекунд. Вынести его в отдельный поток нельзя, так как на выходе будет создан 
наследник DependencyObject, который потом будет орать, что его нельзя вставить куда бы то ни было кроме объектов его родного потока.

Завершающим методом является SetXmlVirtual, который является непубличным на типе TextRange. Он просто вставляет TextElelement в RichTextBox.

В идеале, без последнего метода, вроде, можно обойтись, но надо смотреть как правильно это делать.

Также опущены некоторые некритичные проверки, который Microsoft делал после LoadElement, которые вряд ли всплывут, если только Вы не будете пытаться абы что, а не RTF загрузить.

Using для кода:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Documents;
```

Comment: rtf с картинками?
вот пожалуйста:
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_EjRSiYtUkUeFpvVG1VS1hZMG8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Гм, у меня оно просто моментально открывается...

Core 2 Duo E8400 3.0 GHz, 8 GB RAM, Windows 7

Может всё-таки проблема не в открытии файла, а в остальной анимации?

Comment: @blackoverdose, вытащил через Reflection загрузку и обработку данных в отдельный поток. У меня после такого апгрейда примерно полсекунды всего тормоза при файле в 15 МБ.

Comment: а можно поподробней?)не могу подключить ваш код, ошибки всякие лезут)
на "FirstOrDefault" ругается 
    
    'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'FirstOrDefault' and no extension method 'FirstOrDefault' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).
    

а на Run<MemoryStream> пишет 
    
    'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' does not contain a definition for 'Run'


4,0 Net Framework
теперь осталась ошибка только 

    
    'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' does not contain a definition for 'Run'

Comment: Я добавил Using'и необходимые в исходнике.
А какая версия .NET Framework, кстати, используется-то?

Comment: Net Framework 4.0 использую потому что использоваться программка на Win XP будет)
переключил на 4,5 ошибка исчезла... но мне выше 4,0 нельзя(((
хотя таким способом и вправду намного быстрее файлы открываются

Comment: Берём отсюда официальную библиотечку для поддержки async/await в .NET 4.0 - http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CompilerServices.AsyncTargetingPack

Task.Run<> заменяем на TaskEx.Run<>

С ещё большими граблями можно и на 3.5 при желании запустить)

Comment: нет уж))) я на 4,0 оставлю))) спасибо большое) а можно с Вами как то лично связаться?) может быть подскажете как лучше приложение вообще организовать) а то мне кажется я там просто кашу нагородил)